# Git cherry-pick to integration branch and then revert the original commit from feature branch

Tags: git, git-branch, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

What would be the consequences of reverting the original commit while the same had been cherry-picked to the target branch?

There is a branch (*say* `feature`) with some changes (commit: **A**), while this change was expected to be in another branch (*say* `integration`).
So, I cherry-picked this change (commit: **A**) from `feature` branch to `integration` branch (resulting into a new commit: **AC**, in `integration` branch).

However, due to testing needs, the `feature` branch is not expected to contain this change (commit: **A**) at all.
Hence, I had to revert **A** from the `feature` branch (resulting in a revert commit **AR**, in the `feature` branch).

Now, if later I merge this `feature` branch into the `integration` branch, would there be any issues or conflicts in the changes that had been cherry-picked initially.
[After this merge, integration will have all the 3 commits, *viz.* **A**, **AR**, **AC**]
The commit **AR** will nullify the commit **A**, won't it nullify the commit **AC** too?

Comment: The changes from commit AC in the integration branch could very well vanish when feature is merged into it.  But, even if that happens, it would be easy for you to bring them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should be fine.
AR will only revert A's changes then AC will reinstall them.

Also to note : you could have considered resetting to the commit just before A (`git reset --hard A^`) instead of reverting it, but I guess it's heavily depending on the specifics of your situation, and maybe a bit on workflow style choices.

Comment: I'm not sure things will play out the way you describe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A and AC feature the same changes. How would this fail? I'm pretty sure I had the same case recently and it went great. What am I missing?

Comment: The feature branch contains instructions which revert some changes.  During a merge, these get played on the target branch.  Just because you saw this go a certain way does not necessarily mean anything for the OP's situation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree to that, I was not trying to apply blindly the solution to another problem. But I admit I don't see the problem you seem to be hinting at so far, and of course I'd like to spot the errors or bad assumptions I made.